# Using the subjunctive without "that"

Tags: subjunctive-mood, wish-preterite

One purpose of *that* is to “express a wish or regret.” Even so, can *that* be removed from the following sentence and still leave it OK?

> It is crucial that you be there before Tom arrives.

Comment: In my view 'that', in this sentence, can be, and often is, elided.

Comment: It is not true that `One purpose of` _that_ `is to “express a wish or regret” `. The complementizer _that_ in both tensed and untensed complement clauses is deletable in almost every case, unless it happens to start a sentence. It does not "express" anything; it doesn't ***mean*** anything. Just put that grammar book down slowly, and back away, please.

Comment: In the UK, I believe most people would say 'It is crucial that you get/are there before Tom arrives' or 'It's crucial that you're there before Tom' Omission of 'that' isn't wrong, but doesn't sound right if 'crucial' is used (mixed registers?). On the other hand, 'It's really important [that] you get there before Tom does' sounds fine with or without the complementiser.

Comment: Another very common formulation in everyday spoken U.S. English involves replacing "that you" with "for you to": "It is crucial for you to be there before Tom arrives."

Answer (score 1):

We can leave out "that" if there is no ambiguity.  In

> It is crucial you be there before Tom arrives.

there's no question what it is that's crucial:  you being there before Tom arrives.  So "that" is not necessary.  It's OK to leave it in, but shorter is better.